# Relation of local base with base

Tags: general-topology

Is it true that local base at point $x$ of a topological space is the collection of base elements which contain the point $x$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite, but almost. If we have a base $\mathcal{B}$ for the topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$, then indeed, for every $x \in X$ the subset $\mathcal{B}_x = \{B \in \mathcal{B}: x \in B\}$ is a local base for the topology at $x$. The proof is immediate.

Conversely, if we have a local base $\mathcal{B}_x$ for each $x \in X$, then $\mathcal{B} = \bigcup_{x \in X} \mathcal{B}_x$ is a base for the topology. This is not hard to see, again.

But if we just have one local base at some point $x$, I don't think it needs to be of the form $\mathcal{B_x}$ for some $\mathcal{B}$ which is a base for the whole space; we can consider local bases without considering a global base at all.

Comment: About the last paragraph: the only way for this to fail is for the topology not to be $T_1$. Otherwise, we can put at every $y\neq x$ a local base consisting of open sets containing $y$ but not $x$ and apply your second paragraph. For a non-$T_1$ counterexample, consider the isolated point in Sierpiński's two-point space.

Comment: @tomasz thanks for the addition.